# How to show that a manifold is foliated by stable manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds, foliations

I'm trying to understand how to show explicitly that a manifold may be foliated by the stable manifolds, using the following statements of stable manifold theorem and foliations. I feel like it should be obvious, but I'm not confident enough in my differential geometry to know that I'm right.

STABLE MANIFOLD THEOREM:

> Suppose flow $\phi_t:\mathbb{R}\times M \rightarrow M$ with a
>   hyperbolic invariant set $\Lambda$. Let us define:
>
> - $W^{s}(x)= \{y \in M : \displaystyle{\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}} \|\phi_{t}(y) - \phi_{t}(x)\| =0\}$
> - $W^{u}(x)= \{y \in M : \displaystyle{\lim_{t\rightarrow - \infty}} \|\phi_{t}(y) - \phi_{t}(x)\| =0\}$
>
> Then,
>
> 1. $W^s(x)$ and $W^u(x)$ are smooth manifolds, which are called the stable manifold and unstable manifold respectively.
> 2. $W^s(x)$ and $W^u(x)$ are smooth injective immersions of the bundles $E^s_x$ and $E^u_x$ respectively
> 3. $W^s(x)$ and $W^u(x)$ are tangent to the bundles at $x$: $T(W^s(x))_x =E^s_x$ and $T(W^u(x))_x =E^u_x$.

FOLIATIONS (adapted from this article by Lawson https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183535509):

> An $p$-dimensional, $C^{k}$ foliation of an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ is a decomposition of $M$ into a union of disjoint connected subsets $ \{\mathcal{L}_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in A}$
>   called the *leaves* of the foliation, with the following property:
>   Every point in $M$ has a neighbourhood $U$ and a system of local $C^{k}$ co-ordinates $x=(x_1, ..., x_n):U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that for each leaf $\mathcal{L}_{\alpha}$, the components of $U\cap \mathcal{L}_{\alpha}$ are described by the equations ($x_{p+1}$, ..., $x_n$) =  ($\alpha_{p+1}$, ..., $\alpha_{n}$), where $\alpha_{p+1},..., \alpha_{n}$ are constant values in $\mathbb{R}$.

I know how to show that the $M$ decomposes into a disjoint union of stable manifolds, but I don't know how to define the charts explicitly as per the definition of foliations. (If you know of better definitions, do let me know!) I was thinking of trying to construct submersion of $M$ into $W^s(x)$, because submersions (according to Lawson's article) gives us a foliation by using the Implicit Function Theorem. Not too sure how to go about this though... this is a fact used a lot in the literature but I can't seem to find a simple way of applying the Stable Manifold Theorem to show this is indeed the case.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: As you certainly understand, the charts will depend on the particular system. The construction of the global invariant manifolds comes from the construction of the local invariant manifolds and the latter are graphs over some open set, thus giving your neighborhood. What is your question exactly?

Comment: Probably you mean $l=p$ and something else than "finite disjoint union".

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for replying! Yes, I understand that the construction of global stable manifolds come from the construction of local stable manifolds, which are defined in some small open neighbourhood $U$; I understand that there are charts taking $U$ to $R^n$ since the stable manifold is a manifold.  What I don't see is how these co-ordinates are such that the components of $U\cap L_{\alpha}$ are described by the equations in the above definition of foliations. I'm actually not too sure what this part of the def'n means...

Comment: I see, I suggest that you look for what is usually called the flow box theorem. It is really only a simple application of the implicit function theorem to "straighten out" whatever is "curved" (could be the invariant manifolds, or the curves of a flows, etc). This gives you your coordinates.

Comment: Even more explicit, in case you had the **exact** formulas for the local invariant manifolds. Say that in some coordinates $(u,v)$ they are graphs of the form $(u,\phi(u))$ and $(\psi(v),v)$. Then the new coordinates $x=v - \phi(u)$, $y=u-\psi(v)$ give a possible local system as you want.

Comment: Alright, thanks, that helps! I'll go look that up.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this statement of the Stable Manifold Theorem? I'm looking for a similar result to use in my research. There are too many different forms of this theorem for me to be able to find an applicable one.